# Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory

Tags: bash, gcloud

I'm installing Google Cloud SDK from my terminal.

Then, I got an error when I typed `./install.sh`.
It shows

```
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /Users/myname/.config/gcloud/logs, (Error: Could not create directory [/Users/myname/.config/gcloud/logs/2022.06.18]: Permission denied.

Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory..
The configuration directory may not be writable. To learn more, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations#creating_a_configuration
```

Though I clicked "Yes" in `Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud CLI (y/N)?`
It still shows `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/myname/.config/gcloud'`

Does anyone meet the same issue? I've found some solution on Stackoverflow and other websites, but none of them are useful for me.

Comment: Do you have a directory `/Users/myname/.config/gcloud` and, if so, what are its permissions set to?

Comment: I download ```google-cloud-sdk``` in my User folder

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I solved by:

- Open Finder
- `CMD+SHIFT+G`
- Input `~/.config`
- If `gcloud` directory does not exist, create it.
- Right Click `gcloud` directory > Get Info > Sharing & Permissions > Give "Read & Write" to all levels.

I do not know if this is safe, but it allowed installation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

update on the initial quick fix:
Basically, the issue was I didn't have write permission for directories (folders) I should have access to. To fix it, I ran the command

**sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/**

which sets you as the owner, now able to modify files in your home directory, as ~/ is a shortcut for your home directory (anything in your username directory/folder). *(and $(whoami) means your username)*

---

initial quick fix:
i had the same issue and running the same command with sudo *(in your situation: **sudo ./install.sh**)* worked for me

(you will be prompted to enter your mac password and it will tell you that it works only for the root user)